# Wie kann ich einen Satz mit einer Verneinung formulieren?

Tags: grammar, negation, comparison

> Isn't this dictionary better than the other one?

Ist diese Übersetzung richtig?

> Ist es nicht dieses Wörterbuch besser als das andere?

Aber warum *es*, wenn wir in zwei Wörtern sagen, worum es geht?

> Ist nicht dieses Wörterbuch besser als das andere?

Oder …

> Ist dieses Wörterbuch nicht besser als das andere?

Aber das verändert die Idee. (oder nicht?)

Über die nächste Form habe ich auch nachgedacht, aber ich interessiere mich mehr über die erste.

> Is this dictionary better than the other one or not?
>   Ist dieses Wörterbuch besser als das andere oder nicht?

Comment: The first translation is indeed wrong, which, in my opinion, renders much of the remaining moot.

Comment: Es gibt keine *negativen Sätze*, sondern Sätze, in denen Verneinungen (Negationen) vorkommen. Ich habe den Titel der Frage entsprechend korrigiert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bei einfachen Aussagen** „<Subjekt> ist <Prädikativ>“ gibt es keinen semantischen Unterschied zwischen „nicht-<Prädikativ> sein“ und „<Prädikativ> nicht-sein“. Die gängige Form einer negierten Frage ist hier:

> Ist <Subjekt> nicht <Prädikativ>?

Will man die suggestive Wirkung einer negierten Frage vermeiden, muss man statt „nicht-<Prädikativ>“ eine andere Formulierung wählen (notfalls mit der Vorsilbe „un-“):

> „Ist es nicht möglich, …?“ — „Ist es unmöglich, …?“

**Bei quantifizierten oder bedingten Aussagen** ist das Negieren schwieriger. Dann verwendet man gerne die Form:

> Ist nicht <Aussage ohne *ist*>?

Beispiele:

> „Jede Antwort ist hilfreich.“ — „Ist nicht jede Antwort hilfreich?“
>
> „Eine ist manchmal zu wenig.“ — „Ist nicht eine manchmal zu wenig?“
>
> „Wenn es regnet, ist die Straße nass.“ — „Ist nicht die Straße nass, wenn es regnet?“

Jede andere Position von „nicht“ wäre hier verfremdend oder zumindest verwirrend. Das letzte Beispiel ist zugegebenermaßen eher etwas für Mathematiker als für Linguisten :-)

---

Nichtsdestotrotz und auf die Gefahr hin, obige Aussagen über den Haufen zu werfen:

> Verkäufer: „Von diesem Wörterbuch rate ich ab.“
>
> Kunde: „Ist dieses Wörterbuch nicht besser als das andere?“

Der Kunde stellt hier einfach die gegenteilige Aussage des Verkäufers in Frage. Aber:

> Verkäufer: „Das andere Wörterbuch ist im Sonderangebot.“
>
> Kunde: „Ist nicht dieses Wörterbuch besser als das andere?“

Mit dieser Formulierung vermeidet der Kunde, dem Verkäufer eine Aussage („Dieses Wörterbuch ist schlecht“) in den Mund zu legen. Aber das sind sprachliche Feinheiten, die ich selbst nicht vollständig beherrsche.

Answer (score 2):

Die korrekte Übersetzung ist:

> Ist dieses Wörterbuch nicht besser als das andere?

Wenn Sie aber das *dieses Wörterbuch* (*this dictionary*) betonen, ist die korrekte Übersetzung:

> Ist nicht *dieses Wörterbuch* besser als das andere?

da Sie dann das *dieses Wörterbuch* negieren und das *nicht* der negierten Phrase vorangestellt wird.

Answer (score 1):

Eine direkte Übersetzung wäre:

> Isn't this dictionary better than the other one?

```
Ist dieses Wörterbuch nicht besser als das andere?
```

Den Satz:

> Is this dictionary better than the other one or not?

würde ich nicht direkt übersetzen, sondern sinngemäß:

```
Dieses Wörterbuch wäre besser als das andere, oder? (Was denkst du?)
```

Comment: `Ist dieses Wörterbuch **nicht besser** als das andere?` - das verstehe ich wie `Ist dieses Wörterbuch **schlechter** als das andere?` Oder das ist falsch?

Comment: beides ist möglich, aber das Wort "schlecht" ist besser zu vermeiden..

Comment: @Al.G., das wäre falsch. "Ist dieser Wörterbuch nicht besser als das andere? " hat eine andere Bedeutung als "Ist dieses Wörterbuch schlechter als das andere". Man kann nicht "nicht besser" einfach mit "schlechter"  ersetzen!

Comment: @Iris meint wohl, sie können auch gleich gut sein, dann ist das eine immer noch nicht besser als das andere, ohne schlechter zu sein.

Comment: Ich unterstütze Iris: Bei „Ist x nicht y“ gehört das „nicht“ eindeutig zu „ist“. Da müsste schon viel dazwischen stehen, damit es zu „y“ gehört, etwa: „Ist x denn wirklich nicht y?“

Comment: @user unknown,  nein,  das meinte ich nicht. Es ist so wie Ralph schreibt. "Ist x nicht besser als y?" entspricht "Ist y (nicht) schlechter als x?"

Comment: Ich verstehe zwar jetzt, wie Ralph das meint, ähnlich wie 'regnet es nicht?', oder 'Ist nicht x besser als y?', aber es bleibt dabei, dass die Verneinung der These x sei besser als y auch dann gegeben ist, wenn x nur gleich gut ist wie y. !(a<b) => a >= b.